# Use Same Form Request But Pass Unique Code to The Form Request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I'm implementing a new way to writing Form Request rules and messages where I :

- Have an activity (e.g. adding a user)
- Attach a unique code to each activity (e.g. add_user)
- Write the rules
- Write the Messages on the rules

All this is done over a user interface, and the activities, rules and messages are stored in the DB and fetched as needed:

- Create Form Request
- Fetch rules and messages by passing the activity's unique code
  [image]

This therefore means that all my form requests shall be exactly the same, with the only difference being the code used to fetch the rules and messages. This therefore makes it cumbersome to have to create and import the Form Request every time.

And it made me to wonder, is there a way probably I can use the same Form Request and probably automatically pass to it the code when injecting it in the controller.

Any ideas?

Comment: i think this is bad way )

Comment: How and when do you determine the 'code' you're passing?

Comment: :-) @J.Doe, what exactly is the bad way? Storing them in the DB or the laziness to use the same Form Request?

Comment: @Devon when I'm creating the activity, I know the code I have assigned to it. So when I am in the controller and I want to persist things to the DB, I inject the Form Request and inside it I will have hardcoded the code like in the image above

Comment: Right... that's how you already have it, you're asking how you'd inject the code into the FormRequest object, and I'm asking where you would get the code from in that scenario.

Comment: When i'm importing the Form Request, I would type the code, since I would know what the code should be at that time for that activity e.g. in the controller
`public function saveUser(StandardFormRequest $request('add_user'))`
This is wrong code syntaxwise of course but yeah, hope it shows how i would type the code. The problem is exactly how i would pass it to the form request